# Converting my custom skin_lesion dataset of 600 image in TFRecord format for Deeplabs v3 plus failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, tfrecord, deeplab

I have cloned the deeplabs repository to my drive and added my dataset of 600 images in the deeplabs/datasets/skin_lesion folder. But when i run the script the conversion is not taking place. How  can i fix this issue?

```
!python deeplab/datasets/build_voc2012_data.py \
--image_folder="deeplab/datasets/skin_lesion/JPEGImages" \
--semantic_segmentation_folder="deeplab/datasets/skin_lesion/SegmentationClass" \
--list_folder="deeplab/datasets/skin_lesion/ImageSets/Segmentation" \
--image_format="jpg" \
--output_dir="deeplab/datasets/tfrecord"
```

When  i run the following is shown

```
2020-12-31 18:31:26.264059: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
```

But there is no conversion or creation of any new folder.

Comment: How long did you wait for it to finish?

Comment: It  finished right away.But nothing was created. @geometrikal